# Newbie, can't find a way for this code to work inside webRequest.onBeforeRequest due return

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

EDIT: The problem here was the third line not being written the proper way and it wouldn't work either way. browser.notifications did what I needed.

This is what I currently have. It needs to cancel the request and notify why it has been cancelled. The request cancellation part works fine, however, I am not sure where the notification code should go. I tried by adding innerhtml inside function, but that breaks the code.

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function() {
    getElementsByTagName(body).innerhtml = '<p>Test</p>'; // the problem
        return {cancel: true};
    },
    {
        urls: ["(links)"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen the problem has already been solved, see accepted answer.

Comment: @Makyen Everything you mentioned is included, this is the entire code, manifest.json is alright, since I mentioned that the code works without innerhtml.  The poblem was basic JS and document.getElementsByTagName() not working for this sort of code. I used browser.notifications instead and everything is working fine now.

Comment: I'm aware you got answers which pointed to basic JS issues. Both answers appear to be from people that have no experience in WebExtensions. However, there appear to be *probable* misconceptions regarding WebExtensions architecture implied by the code snippet you provided. Using `webRequest.onBeforeRequest` and trying to affect the DOM in the same code is quite unusual, and usually a bad idea and won't work as intended (it might, but...). Without the *manifest.json* we don't know the context/scope in which the code is running which would say if `getElementsByTagName` is remotely appropriate.

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Anatomy of a WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension) page (and perhaps work through reading the pages linked from there). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: @Makyen Thank you for linking me to that page, it has helpful information that I may need in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [what Paul said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41292648/7332535), I think you probably want body to be a string:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerhtml
```

Comment: Great catch, it now stops the request, but it still doesn't change the body tag.

Comment: Nevermind, seems like changing innerhtml isn't a solution. You fixed the code and answered my question, so I am going to mark this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things in there. First, getElementsByTagName is not a function on the global scope, it's on the document scope.  Second, it returns an array of elements (even if it's an array of just one 'body' element).  So what you might be trying to do is this:

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerhtml = '<p>Test</p>';
        return {cancel: true};
    },
    {
        urls: ["(links)"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: By function, I meant the second line. Thank you for fixing getElementsByTagName(body)[0], sadly it still does not work.

Comment: I re-read what you said about the function part, forget what I said on the first comment. Sadly still not working.

Comment: Afaik 'document' is not available in the illustrated scope? not sure though.